# UWP : How to debug App on VS without uninstall current one?

Tags: c#, uwp

hello I have a UWP debug question:

1. I developped a App called 'MyApp' on VS2017
2. I published MyApp to Windows Store.
3. Download & install MyApp from Windows Store.

Then I want to fix some bugs, I open MyApp project in VS2017, and try to deploy(otherwise cannot debug), then VS notified me : Already installed MyApp, if you conitnue deploy, will uninstall current.

means from now on, every time I want to update MyApp(VS) on VS, I have to uninstall MyApp(WinStore) first? with losing all of my app state? sounds ridiculous.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I debug an app that I should change its name.

Open the Package.appxmanifest.

[image]

Change the package name and display name.

Comment: it worked! also better to change DisplayName in Application tag. 非常感谢兄弟

Comment: As a potential non-programming alternative to this: Virtual Machines. With all the stuff I have to install with VS and maybe SQL Server, I switched to generally running Development only in VM's (the actuall VS projects are on the Host, thanks to shared folders). And depending on the VM Monitor used, it might even support making Snapshoots.

Comment: @OhMyDog Glad to help you and now that it's hard to find a uwp dever in China.

Comment: @Christopher yes that my final option if lindexi's solution not work. But now I prefer use his because of VM is not work well on my machine. thank you anyway.

Comment: @lindexi I totally agree with you, there's no living soil for UWP in China and I do it just because of my respect to Microsoft.